# Image upload to server errors

Tags: android, image-uploading

I am following this tutorial on how to upload an image to a server.

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/#comment-10084

There were a couple errors that I got but eclipse fixed them(hopefully?)

now the error I get is this line:

```
HttpResponse <span class="IL_AD" id="IL_AD3">response</span>= httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

While compiling. It says

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Syntax error on tokens, TypeArgumentList1 expected instead  NewSpotActivity.java    /AndroidConnectingToPhpMySQL/src/com/example/androidhive    line 142    Java Problem
```

It also underlines `</span>` which when I change to just `<span>` it doesn't.

Thank you in advance

Comment: you need to elaborate more on your issue. seems exactly as the error describes, NewSpotActivity.java is there instead of TypeArgumentList1. Have you checked what is supposed to call TypeArgumentList1 and see if it is calling wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please remove `</span>` `<span>` and `<span class="IL_AD" id="IL_AD3">`

I was editing the question, since i thought i was an error when pasting the code here, but i can see that you actually have it in the code. thats an error form the website where you found the code.

Comment: Ooooh okay that makes sense then. Thank you. I don't think it is working but that did fix the crash :D

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [this](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) library. It handles post requests with multipart and it will definitely fit your needs ;)

Comment: I added that but it didn't seem to work. It is still giving the same error :( you wouldn't happen to know of maybe any other/better ways to upload an image? I already have to app sending data to a wamp server, I'm assuming with JSONParse, if I'm understanding it right.